# My Django REST admin page shows locally but in production I get a 404. What am I missing?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The actual API is working fine. My only issue is that the '/admin' route 404's in production.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from appname import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('people/', views.people_list)
]
```

Comment: What if you visit `/admin/`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it redirects to /admin then 404's still